# React - iterate over array of React.element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to assign an array of React.elements to another array using [property spread notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) but in some cases it doesn't work properly.

```js
markers = {};
const markersSelected = [];

if (cached) {
   console.log("Cached");
   // works properly when array is added from cached property
   markersSelected.push(...markers[day][category]);
} else {
    const convertedMarkers = convertUrlToMarkers(files[day][category]);
    console.log(convertedMarkers);
    // can assign properly
    // skipping check for day for better visibility
    markers = {...updateMarkers, [day]: {[category]: convertedMarkers}};
    
    console.log("Converted Markers Expanded:");
    
    // shows nothing, see screenshot
    console.log(...convertedMarkers);
    markersSelected.push(...convertedMarkers);
    
    // I have tried a `for(let marker of convertedMarkers){console.log(marker)}` but there were NO iteration cycle
}
```

Please see screenshot from Console.
[Screenshot from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTrF4.png)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: do console log `console.log(convertedMarkers);`

Comment: It's already there. Please see screenshot.

Comment: I think hes meaning change console.log(...convertedMarkers) to console.log(covertedMarkers) as this might be causing an issue.

Comment: @JJMWilz thanks for comment. If I change it to `console.log(convertedMarkers)`, it displays the same as few lines above in the code snippet (you can see result in the screenshot). I want to put all elements from `convertedMarkers` to `markersSelected` but If I change it to `markersSelected.push(convertedMarkers);` I will push array into array and that's the problem. (result will be like `[[....], [....]]`)

Comment: In that case you could just set markerSelected instead of pushing into it. Try markerSelected = [...convertedMarkers] and then log out markerSelected.